# Random Background Php / Html ?

Tags: php, html, css

Hey i want on my Page a Random BG everytime a User visit that Page.

At the moment i simple use

```
<body background="./images/bgs/random/<?php echo rand(1,13); ?>.jpg">
```

But now when a User logs in -> or a other Page Reload ... the Background changes too and thats a but ugly.

So my Question is there a better way or a solve so that the bg is loading only once ? with sessions or something idk

Every Answer is welcome thanks! 
:)

Comment: so you only want the background to change once per session?

Comment: do you want to annoy and lose visitors, because this is how you  annoy and lose visitors

Comment: yes like a user visit site bg 1 ... when he leave and visit again then another but not when you click on a link or something or press a button on site :)

Comment: @Dagon why ? what is the reason that visitors gone ? 
Please explain.

Comment: would you enjoy finding a new wall colour every time you walked in the  kitchen. human brains prefer consistency and predictability

Comment: Its an argument and a point to think about. 
But it is looking good and its something other ? 
Do you really think that random Images disturbs this much ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `$_SESSION`. Make sure that you use `session_start()` before any headers are sent.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['background'])){
  $_SESSION['background'] = rand(1,13);
  // now just use $_SESSION['background']
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['bg'])) {
  $_SESSION['bg'] = rand(1, 13);
}
?>

<!-- background is very old, use css for this ;) -->
<body background="./images/bgs/random/<?php echo $_SESSION['bg']; ?>.jpg">
```

Also with `session_destroy()` you can reset your own session.

Comment: And where i can reset my sessions at best Point ?

Comment: You would want to use `unset($_SESSION['bg'])` to unset the session variable then use `session_destroy()`.

Comment: You can destory your sessions everywhere you want (after the session_start())